# Delphi - MadCrypt - Problem encrypting and decrypting a string

Tags: delphi, encryption

I am trying to encrypt a string but often only part of the string is being encrypted.  I don't see anyone else having this problem so I am probably doing something wrong.  I have the same problem in Delphi 2007 and 2009.  I am using Win XP SP3.  Here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sTestToConvert: ansistring;
  sPassword: ansistring;
begin
  sTestToConvert := trim(Memo1.Text);
  sPassword := trim(Edit1.Text);
  madCrypt.Encrypt(sTestToConvert, sPassword);
  Memo2.Text := sTestToConvert;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sTextToConvert: ansistring;
  sPassword: ansistring;
begin
  sPassword := trim(Edit1.Text);
  sTextToConvert := trim(memo2.Text);
  madCrypt.Decrypt(sTextToConvert, sPassword);
  Memo1.Text := sTextToConvert;
end;
```

I also have the same problem when trying to use OldEncrypt and OldDecrypt.  Any ideas on what is causing the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean when you say "only part of the string is being encrypted." Do you mean that you can still see some of the plaintext in `sTestToConvert` even after calling `Encrypt`?

More likely, I expect you mean that when you call `Decrypt`, you only get part of the original string back.

That's because `Encrypt` may store *any* byte value in the result, including non-printing characters, even `#0`, the null character. When you store such a string in a `TMemo` or `TEdit`, the underlying Windows control treats the `#0` character as the end of the string. It doesn't store the rest of the encrypted value. Thus, when you call `Decrypt` on what's stored in the edit control, you are only decrypting a portion of what you originally had.

If you want to have a text version of the encrypted data, use the `Encode` and `Decode` functions; the [documentation online](http://help.madshi.net/madCryptUnit.htm) mentions this. Those use base-64 encoding.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sTestToConvert: AnsiString;
  sPassword: AnsiString;
begin
  sTestToConvert := Trim(Memo1.Text);
  sPassword := Trim(Edit1.Text);
  madCrypt.Encrypt(sTestToConvert, sPassword);
  Memo2.Text := madCryt.Encode(sTestToConvert);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  sTextToConvert: AnsiString;
  sPassword: AnsiString;
begin
  sPassword := Trim(Edit1.Text);
  sTextToConvert := madCrypt.Decode(Memo2.Text);
  madCrypt.Decrypt(sTextToConvert, sPassword);
  Memo1.Text := sTextToConvert;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Rob...that was the problem and it is now working.  I appreciate the help.